# dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Permission denied

Tags: dnsmasq

can anyone help me with this error message I get when I start dnsmasq?
I have read another thread on askubtuntu.com but I couldn solve the problem.
I want dnsmasq to block certain domains...
Ihanks!

Comment: Did you run as `root`?  Ports under 1024 can only be bound by the `root` user. https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html

Comment: What *version* of Ubuntu are you using? recent versions use `systemd-resolved`, and that will be bound to port 53 already, likely preventing `dnsmasq` from doing so

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Actually I forgot about the problem. I din t run into it again (have a new laptop)...